# Where should I ask for open source license choice

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I put my question about which open source license is best for my project?

Comment: Probably nowhere.  There are places to ask specific questions about a licence, but not so much, "which license should I use?"

Comment: Then where I can ask specific question about a license or, if you can, recommend me a site, to ask "guessing" question.

Comment: There *is* no site where "guessing" questions would be on topic.  It sounds like you don't have a specific question about a specific licence or licensing, so your question *wouldn't* be on topic.

Comment: There are some on Programmers.SE.

Comment: @Scimonster A question like this wouldn't be on topic on programmers.

Comment: @Servy I posted as a comment because as I'm not an active member of the site, I don't know what goes.

Comment: I mean site outside StackExchange network. If you're able to recommend it here

Comment: @rozpuszczalny _"I mean site outside StackExchange network"_ Ouch! I'm not sure if this also applying for Meta, but usually asking for off-site links is off-topic. Though some (easily to google) site like [choosealicense.com](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/) might contain useful information for you (Don't forget to have a review from your companies employed lawyer though, whatever you choose).

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for. Yep, I think too it's a bit off-topic now. Anyway, I got my answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Questions about software licensing - that don't require legal expertise - are on topic on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). However, questions about "the best" rarely fare well on Stack Exchange sites. We tend to favour specific and answerable questions over broad and chatty ones (for more details see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask))

The first thing you should do is browse the site's [licensing questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Blicensing%5D%20closed%3A0). That should give you a fairly good idea of how specific we expect you to be. And you might even stumble upon an answer that answers your question (e.g. [Choosing a licence for open source projects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12394/choosing-a-licence-for-open-source-projects)). If not, you should go ahead and ask. Be prepared to respond to any comments asking for clarifications.